# Java - Using TryCatch outside a method

Tags: java

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Images {
    try {
        public static Image button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
    } catch(SlickException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This just gives an error, I want to be able to store some images in static variables and access them from another class without instantiating it.

I could possibly make a method to initialise all them and set values to them, but then the variables wouldn't be static.

The reason I need TryCatch is because the constructor of the `Image` class throws a `SlickException`

Comment: What error ? Can you give us more details, pls ?

Comment: Maybe also add `final`. Then the compiler forces you to think about what to assign in that catch block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two options:

- Use a static initializer block

  ```
  public static final Image button;

  static {
      try/catch in here, assign to button
  }
  ```
- Use a method for initialization

  ```
  public static final Image button = createButton();

  private static Image createButton() {
      try/catch in here
  }
  ```

Personally I'm somewhat skeptical of this being a good idea though - making type initialization do "real work" can lead to bugs which are hard to track down. Is all the referring code *really* set up for it to be null in the case of problems?

Comment: initializing images in static initializers sucks as you either eat the exception, returning null (or whoops img) or crash the entire application with following LinkageError(s), sometimes masked and eaten and unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your exception handling code in a `static` block.

```
public static Image button;

static {
   try {
       button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
    } catch(SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the static variable outside the block..and it will work..

```
public static final Image button = setImageButt();

public static Image setImageButt(){
   try {
       button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
    } catch(SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to place it into a static block

```
 public static Image button;
    static{
          try {
                button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
            } catch(SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use static constructor.

```
public class Images {
    public static Image button;

    static{
        try {
            button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");     
        } catch(SlickException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a static block for initialization and take extra care to not swallow the exception:

```
public class Images {

    public final static Image BUTTON;
    static {
        Image i;
        try {
            i = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
        BUTTON = i;
    }
}
```

I corrected some things from your code:

- Creating the image in initializer implies it should be a constant, thus *final*.
- Constants should have uppercase names, thus *BUTTON*.
- Exceptions during initialization should not be swallowed but properly indicated. Otherwise you can spend hours debugging the image not being found because there will be no indication initialization failed. ExceptionInInitializerError is the standard exception to throw in that case.

There are other solutions, but this is the cleanest IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem once and while for finding the solution I just came across to this question. I have solved similar problem just putting all of the code in the default constructor.

Your solution code will be like this:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Images {

    public Images{
        try {
        public static Image button = new Image("images/buttons/0/Button.png");
        } catch(SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```