# Syntax errors, but i see no errors

Tags: java, syntax

In eclipse it giving me a bunch of syntax errors, but i see that the code is perfectly fine??? Line 14, 23, 27 have syntax errors, but like i said, they seem perfectly fine to me? :(

```
package me.slappy826.Everlost.ttf;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;

public class SlickTTF
{
    InputStream fontFile = org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("assets/everlost/Ubuntu-LI.ttf");
    private static TrueTypeFont font;

    private Font awtFont = null;

    try 
    {
        awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
        awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(20f);
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);
    } catch(Exception e) {}


    public static void drawString(String s, int i, int j, Color color)
    {
        font.drawString(i, j, s, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are lines 14, 23 and 27?

Comment: Line 14 is private Font awtFont = null; | Line 23 is  public static void drawString(String s, int i, int j, Color color) | Line 27 is the last line.

Comment: You should declare your try/catch-block either inside of a method/constructor or inside of a static-block as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776987/java-using-trycatch-outside-a-method)

Comment: When reporting an error, **always copy/paste the EXACT and COMPLETE error message into your question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a try-catch in class level scope, just put it inside a method. Here is an example with a possible constructor that initializes your members:

```
public SlickTTF(){
    try{
        awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
        awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(20f);
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Now you can create an SlickTTF object as `SlickTTF example = new SlickTTF()` and it will have the class attributes initialized correctly